# Why am I losing exactly 5 bytes during decoding in my netty pipeline?

Tags: java, netty

I'm writing a netty pipeline for a protocol which is able to transfer files and structured messages. File transfers are initiated with a structured message (handshake) followed by a stream of bytes representing the file.

The exact message flow for an incoming file looks like this (server being my netty implementation, client another software):

```
            +---------+                                    +---------+
            | Client  |                                    | Server  |
            +---------+                                    +---------+
                 |                                              |
                 | Connect (1)                                  |
                 |--------------------------------------------->|
                 |                                              |
                 | Handshake to announce incoming file (2)      |
                 |--------------------------------------------->|
                 |                                              |
                 |                Acknowledge file transfer (3) |
                 |<---------------------------------------------|
                 |                                              |
                 | Send file (4)                                |
                 |--------------------------------------------->|
```

The protocol message looks like this:

```
            +---------+----------------+----------------+
            | Length  |      Type      | Actual Message |
            | 4 bytes |     1 byte     |   N bytes      |
            +---------+----------------+----------------+
```

In the case of the handshake message, the `Actual Message` only consists of a single `Long` value, the `token`.

Here's the ReplayingDecoder:

```
    public class ProtocolDecoder extends ReplayingDecoder<State> {

      private Integer msgType;
      private Long token;


      public enum State {
        LENGTH,
        MSG_TYPE,
        TOKEN
      }

      public ProtocolDecoder() {
        super(State.LENGTH);
      }

      @Override
      protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {

        switch (state()) {

          case LENGTH:
            // (2) read the message length from the handshake
            long messageLength = in.readUnsignedIntLE();
            checkpoint(State.MSG_TYPE);

          case MSG_TYPE:
            // (2) read the message type from the handshake
            msgType = in.readBoolean();
            checkpoint(State.TOKEN);

          case TOKEN:
            try {
              // (2) read the token from the handshake
              token = in.readUnsignedIntLE();
              // (3) write back the acknowledgement
              ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(new Acknowledgement(token));
              // (4) done reading the protocol message
              // now switch to the file protocol
              ctx.pipeline().addLast(new FileInboundHandler());
              // write everything that is still in the buffer to the
              // modified pipeline
              ByteBuf rest = in.readBytes(super.actualReadableBytes());
              out.add(rest);
              // remove the protocol handshake decoder and pass
              // the rest of this channel to the `FileInboundHandler`
              ctx.pipeline().remove(this);
            } finally {
              reset();
            }
            break;
          default:
            throw new Error("Shouldn't reach here.");
        }
      }

      private void reset() {
        token = null;
        msgType = null;
      }
```

The `FileInboundHandler` simply creates a file and writes all `ByteBuf`s to it.

This is working in principle, with the only problem being that each file misses exactly 5 bytes at the beginning.

I have 2 questions:

1) If I put a `LoggingHandler` as the first handler in the pipeline, can I be sure that all traffic on the socket is logged, no matter if my decoders are buggy?

2) When calling `ctx.channel().writeAndFlush()`, does it flush only the "outbound" buffer, meaning I can be sure I'm not flushing any bytes I have not consumed from the inbound buffer yet?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you've forgotten to put a `break;` at the end of the statements for each switch case? Looking at it now, from the first `LENGTH` read it's gonna fall through to the type and token reads, getting 5 bytes too many: the boolean (one byte) and the token (read as unsigned int, 4 bytes).

Comment: i've already tried that in a previous version of the decoder (putting a `break;` in every case), but the behavior was the same. Also the [ReplayingDecoder documentation](https://github.com/firebase/netty/blob/master/codec/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/ReplayingDecoder.java#L149-L199) does use the fall through mechanism too - i assumed that was the idea behind the checkpoints.

Comment: @pulse00 Hmm, seems to make sense. After all you can just read the header in one go and the decoder is removed from the pipeline at the end. What about the handler for the file, does it include this protocol header?